# Monitoring process activities using system calls only (without utilities like `top`)

Tags: linux, process, memory, monitoring

I want to obtain information about memory used by different users and different processes which users are running and statistics about those processes like memory consumption, execution speed, etc., using Linux system calls.

I don't want to use commands like `free`, `top` etc. Can anyone suggest how to do so?

Comment: The `/proc` filesystem is the typical source of this kind of information.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand how memory is used.  A significant portion of memory is often shared.  Any code used in a program and it's libraries are shared between different processes.  Code is mapped into memory as read-only and is shared by all processes so it not owned by any one user.  Certain libraries like `libc` are used by practically every single process, but are only loaded in RAM once.  Programs that are more code heavily will have more shared memory than programs that are more data heavy.

To answer your question, nearly all the information that programs like top, free, and ps get comes from scanning the `/proc` filesystem.  Every process has it's own folder named after it's PID.  In there are a number of files like maps that show's it's memory map, comm that shows the command that was executed to start the process, and io that shows I/O usage.  There's an introduction to `/proc` in the [Linux Kernel Documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use following method.I am showing an example :

- Consider that I need to know information about firefox browser that is running on my Linux Box. I will follow below steps :

  1. Get PID of firefox :

  `[shubham@system-dev ~]$ ps -aux | grep firefox
  Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
  shubham  24790 17.5 25.8 1679220 1038440 ?     Sl   09:15  26:02 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox`

  2. Now use /proc FS with "PID" to see various information (an example for  firefox on my linux box is given below)
     `[shubham@system-dev ~]$ cat /proc/24790/status
     Name:   firefox
     State:  S (sleeping)
     Tgid:   24790
     Pid:    24790
     PPid:   29843
     TracerPid:      0
     Uid:    501     501     501     501
     Gid:    0       0       0       0
     Utrace: 0
     FDSize: 256
     Groups: 0
     VmPeak:  1682804 kB
     VmSize:  1679412 kB
     VmLck:         0 kB
     VmPin:         0 kB
     VmHWM:   1183048 kB
     VmRSS:   1040800 kB
     VmData:  1453848 kB
     VmStk:       152 kB
     VmExe:        64 kB
     VmLib:     61296 kB
     VmPTE:      2828 kB
     VmSwap:   147048 kB
     Threads:        24
     SigQ:   1/31287
     SigPnd: 0000000000000000
     ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
     SigBlk: 0000000000000000
     SigIgn: 0000000001001000
     SigCgt: 00000001800044ef
     CapInh: 0000000000000000
     CapPrm: 0000000000000000
     CapEff: 0000000000000000
     CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
     Cpus_allowed:   f
     Cpus_allowed_list:      0-3
     Mems_allowed:   1
     Mems_allowed_list:      0
     voluntary_ctxt_switches:        2604819
     nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     560691`
  3. You can use many files under /proc// directory for monitoring purpose (ex: mem, io,stat.stack etc)

NOTE: For using with syscalls only, you will need syscalls like: open(), creat(), close(), read() etc.

I hope you could understand the answer!